# How add fielter to one2many tree view?

Tags: python, odoo

This is feedback.form .py file
        from openerp.osv import fields, osv
        from openerp import api
        import logging

```
    class feedback_form(osv.Model):
        _name = 'feedback.form'
        _rec_name = 'company_id111'
        _columns = {
            'company_id111': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
            'completed': fields.boolean('Completed',default=False,readonly=False,required=False),

            'frequency' : fields.char('Frequency'),
            'shutdown' : fields.char('Shut Down'),
            'insp_rslt' : fields.one2many('feedback.tree','insp_rsltts','Inspection Result',),

        }

        def get_detail_emp(self, cr, uid, ids, folionum, context=None):
            val = {}
                res = []
                if folionum:
                        for mom in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr,uid,folionum,context=context):
                            val = {
                                        'inspec_type' : mom.inspection_name,

                                     }
                            res.append(val)

                return {'value': val} 


    feedback_form()

    class feedback_tree(osv.Model):
        _name = 'feedback.tree'
        _rec_name = 'insp_rsltts'
        STATUS = [
            ('0', 'Completed'),
            ('1', 'Not-Completed'),
        ]

        _columns = {
            'folionum' : fields.many2one('calendar.event','Maintenance ID',),
            'folio_number' : fields.many2one('asset.asset','Folio number',),
            'inspec_type' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Inspection Type',),
            'insp_msr1' : fields.many2one('results.measure','Attributes',),
            'valuess' : fields.char('Values'),
            'status' : fields.selection(STATUS,'Status'),
            'insp_rsltts': fields.many2one('feedback.form','Result Id'),


        }
        def onchange_insp(self, cr, uid, ids, folionum,context=None):
            dids = []
            res = {}
            for record in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr, uid, folionum, context=context):
                dids = [x.id for x in record.inspection_name]
            dids1 = []
            for record in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr, uid, folionum, context=context):
                dids1 = [x.id for x in record.folio_num1]
            res.update({'inspec_type':[('id','in',dids)]})
            res.update({'folio_number':[('id','in',dids1)]})
            return {'domain':res}

        def onchange_measure(self, cr, uid, ids, inspec_type, context=None):
            dids = []
            for record in self.pool.get('asset1.inspection').browse(cr, uid, inspec_type, context=context):
                dids = [x.id for x in record.msr_insp]
            return {'domain':{'insp_msr1':[('id','in',dids)]}}


    feedback_tree()


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

    <!-- Form & Tree View for Visitor Register -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="feed_back_event">
            <field name="name">feedback.form.form</field>
            <field name="model">feedback.form</field>

            <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form string="feedback">
                    <group>
                       <!-- <field name="number"/>-->
            <field name="company_id111"/>







            </group>
            <hr/><group>
            <!--<group><group><field name="insp_msr1" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/></group><group>--><field name="insp_rslt">            <tree string="Insp Result" editable="bottom">

                <field name="folionum" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}" on_change="onchange_insp(folionum)"/>
            <!--<field name="place" on_change="onchange_place(place)"/>-->
            <field name="folio_number" options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/>


            <field name="inspec_type" on_change="onchange_measure(inspec_type)"/>
            <field name="insp_msr1"/>
            <field name="valuess"/>
            <field name="status"/>  
            </tree>
            </field>


            </group>





        <group>
            <field name="completed"/></group>
               </form>
    </field>
        </record>




    <record id="feed_back_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Maintenance Feedback Form</field>
            <field name="res_model">feedback.form</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>    

            <field name="help" type="html">
                    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click to create a new Maintenance Feedback</p>
            </field>    
            </record>
    **<record id="feed_back_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Feedback</field>
            <field name="model">feedback.form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="Feedback">

                    <!--<field name="completed" />-->

                    <group expand="0" string="Group By">

                        <filter string="Pending" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'insp_rslt'}"/>

                    </group>
                </search>
             </field>
         </record>**
    <menuitem id="feedback_configs" name="Maintenance Feedback"/>
        <menuitem id="substation_feedback_menu" name="Maintenance Feedback " parent="base.menu_mro_root"/>
        <menuitem id="feed_back_creation" name="Maintenance Feedback Form" parent="substation_feedback_menu" action="feed_back_action"/>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

How to add Group by of **status** field of feedback.tree class in xml file. I have trie with some possibalities but i dint get

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-box this is limitation, so you need create some work around to this. what you can do here is on Model `feedback.form` you can create one compute text field and store the `state` of the o2m field `insp_rslt` *(make sure to make compute field is `store=True`)*, and then add the field in the view which will allow you todo filtering and grouping on compute field.

Yes, You can say here the 02M field record can have multiple states, for that you can store them as text field and it will let you filter based on contains. Or you can aggregate and store one state making compute selection field.

Bests